# Elastic Date: The date gets stored as OffsetDateTime in an object format

Tags: java, date, elasticsearch, date-format

The data I am indexing into elastic is an OffsetDateTime from Java in the following manner.

```
Timestamp closedDate = resultSet.getTimestamp("closedon");
org.threeten.bp.OffsetDateTime offsetDate= Instant.ofEpochMilli(closedDate.toInstant().toEpochMilli())
                    .atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC)
```

I am storing this offsetDate into elastic and it converts into the following..

```
"closedDate": {
                        "dateTime": {
                            "date": {
                                "year": 2020,
                                "month": 6,
                                "day": 15
                            },
                            "time": {
                                "hour": 11,
                                "minute": 26,
                                "second": 1,
                                "nano": 37000000
                            }
                        }
```

I want to use something simple like the following to query it but its not working because the formats are all different. How do I go about changing the format of the data that is getting indexed?

```
{
           "range": {
            "closedDate": {
              "gte": "2021-05-22T00:00:00.000Z",
              "lte": "2021-02-01T00:00:00.000Z",
              "format": "strict_date_optional_time"
            }
          }
        }
```

Mapping:

```
"closedOn": {
                    "properties": {
                        "dateTime": {
                            "properties": {
                                "date": {
                                    "properties": {
                                        "day": {
                                            "type": "long"
                                        },
                                        "month": {
                                            "type": "long"
                                        },
                                        "year": {
                                            "type": "long"
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "time": {
                                    "properties": {
                                        "hour": {
                                            "type": "long"
                                        },
                                        "minute": {
                                            "type": "long"
                                        },
                                        "nano": {
                                            "type": "long"
                                        },
                                        "second": {
                                            "type": "long"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
```

Comment: Can you please share your index mapping ? I don't think 'closedDate' is of type 'date'

Comment: @SahilGupta, unable to put the mapping here in comments so I have edited the question with the mapping..

Comment: wl change the mapping and try @SahilGupta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes the index was mapped wrongly, I used a json serializer and it works fine now after the mapping is of "type":"date".

Thanks Sahil Gupta.